# How do I change the server of a Power BI gateway after dozens of reports have been pointed to it?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, data-gateway, powerbi-datagateway

We are currently using an on-premises data gateway to allow our reports in the app.powerBI.com web interface use an on-premise SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) server tabular model for their data source. Dozens of reports, workspaces, and other PowerBI objects are all running off of this gateway.

We now need to move this SSAS server to a different server for resource management reasons.

If I go to https://app.powerbi.com/ click the "settings" gear and open the "manage gateways" page, I can find the detail I want to change, the "Server" value here:

[image: screenshot of PowerBI gateway settings, showing the server field]

But that field is disabled for every admin that has tried. I believe if I could change this field, my problems would be solved.

We looked into doing it through the API, but it appears it is also not editable via API calls related to the gateway: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/gateways

Changing the gateway seemed like the path of least resistance. If anyone knows how to do that, please let me know.

The second idea we had was create a second gateway and point all existing dashboards, reports, workspaces, etc. to the new gateway. However, we have a lot of non-technical users that we can't expect to go in and do this themselves on things they have created, so if we do this it must be via the API. It appears I could do this for things the user calling the API has in their "My Workspace" but I don't see where I could do something like "Find all objects using Gateway 1 and point to Gateway 2 instead"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround might be to delete the data source which is no longer required and then create a new data source with the same name under the same cluster with all the necessary changes to the server name.

Comment: This will not work, there is an underlying GUID that is being used by all objects referencing the data source, they are not matching to the data source by name, otherwise changing the name of the data source would break all existing reports.

Comment: The only possible way I can think of is changing the data source setting in the Desktop file and re-uploading it to the Service along with a new data source to the gateway. I see that you say there are many non-technical users who use it but there seems to be no other alternative.